# Unable to initialize Log4j - SLF4JLoggerContextFactory while migrating log4j(v1) to log4j2 (v2)

Tags: java, log4j2

I have Spring integration application. where i have migrated log4j.1.x to log4j2. After migrating It is not logging anything and there is the following error on startup:
ERROR StatusLogger LogManager returned an instance of org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory which does not implement org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory. Unable to initialize Log4j.

**Web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>file:///opt/ds-log4j2.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

**Pom.xml** : log4j2 dependencies.

```
<!-- Log4j2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Tried to add LOG4J to SLF4J adaptor too but its not working.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Since this is a spring integration application. solution provided on the following link is not applicable : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036773/unable-to-initialize-log4j-slf4jloggercontextfactory](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Integration. See if `log4j-slf4j-impl` instead helps you somehow: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html

Comment: If we use log4j-slf4j-impl instead of log4j-to-slf4j then getting following error: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j

Comment: Well, if you get that error, then you don't do instead, but alongside. You have to remove  `log4j-to-slf4j` dependency.

Comment: Thank you Artem bilan, It is working as expected after removing the log4j-to-slf4j dependency.